# JQuery window.location.assign method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I've struggled with this problem for two days. I googled it and see some similar cases.

After sending POST request to the server, I wanna redirect the page to another one. The POST function works properly but `window.location.assign()` method doesn't work (although it works in another part of my project).

Here is my code:

```
const $btnDel = $("<button>", {
    appendTo: $('td:eq(0)', $tr),
    "class": "revertButton",
    html: "<i class='material-icons'>restore</i>",
    on: {
        click: function () {
            console.log(`Reverting: ${book.name}`)
            $.post(`/revert/${book.name}`, {
                bookName: `${book.name}`,
                pageCount: `${book.pageCount}`,
                action: "REVERT"
            }).done(() => {
                window.location.assign('/bookPage');
            })
        }
    }
});
```

The first console.log works (I mean `console.log("Reverting: ${book.name}"`), but done function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below code.

```
const $btnDel = $("<button>", {
    appendTo: $('td:eq(0)', $tr),
    "class": "revertButton",
    html: "<i class='material-icons'>restore</i>",
    on: {
        click: function () {
            console.log(`Reverting: ${book.name}`)
            $.post(`/revert/${book.name}`, () => {
                bookName: `${book.name}`,
                pageCount: `${book.pageCount}`,
                action: "REVERT"
            }).done(() => {
                window.location.assign('/bookPage');
            }).fail(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this will give you some help/clue.

Comment: yes. that is what I mentioned below in my response that it will give us some clue to solve the problem, trying to help and learn along. Unsure, why downvoted.

Comment: Did it enter the done function or the fail function?

Comment: yeah I wrote both of them:

....
                                }).done(function() {
                                    window.location.assign('/bookPage');
                                }).fail(function(e) {
                                    console.log(e);
                                })
                            }

it doesn't print anything!

Comment: add the console.log() functions inside done and fail functions with some string. ex: `console.log("Inside done");` check if it enters any of those.. else we have to debug the function within `$.post`